# New navigation: Can't filter by tag in the "popular" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

In the new navigation I can't filter the "popular" tab by tags, even though I can filter all the other tabs.

Every other tab has the filter menu, but the popular tab doesn't. Is this by design? It seems like a bug to me but maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and is now deployed.